# Magento 2 : How to implement Travis CLI in my custom module?

Tags: magento2, module, cli, travis

I've some modules to Magento 2.0 and 2.1, so I'd like to implement the Travis CLI to install the Magento and test my extension in some Magento versions and PHP versions, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get something on this ? If yes could you please share :)

Comment: @KeyurShah I answered it now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your file **.travis.yml** like that example:

```
dist: trusty
language: php
php:
  - 5.6
  - 7.0

env:
  - TEST_SUITE=unit
  - TEST_SUITE=phpcs
  - TEST_SUITE=marketplaceeqp

before_script:
  - sleep 60

script:
  - wget https://github.com/magento/magento2/archive/2.0.2.zip
  - unzip -qq 2.0.2.zip
  - cd magento2-2.0.2/
  - wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/centerax/5e42abec89d62a1308ba/raw/4b3242361c0690e234266afb3520c2940ac1055a/auth.json
  - composer require --prefer-source --no-interaction ebizmarts/magento2-magemonkey:dev-develop
  - sh -c "if [ '$TEST_SUITE' = 'unit' ]; then /bin/cp ../phpunit_config.xml dev/tests/unit/ && ./vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit_config.xml --coverage-text; fi"
  - sh -c "if [ '$TEST_SUITE' = 'phpcs' ]; then composer require --prefer-source --no-interaction "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*" magento-ecg/coding-standard && vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/scripts/phpcs --config-set installed_paths vendor/magento-ecg/coding-standard && ./vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/scripts/phpcs -n --standard="EcgM2" ./vendor/ebizmarts/magento2-magemonkey/; fi"
  - sh -c "if [ '$TEST_SUITE' = 'marketplaceeqp' ]; then composer require --prefer-source --no-interaction squizlabs/php_codesniffer magento/marketplace-eqp && vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/scripts/phpcs --config-set installed_paths vendor/magento/marketplace-eqp && ./vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/scripts/phpcs -n --standard="MEQP2" ./vendor/ebizmarts/magento2-magemonkey/; fi"
```

Comment: How you are running this I mean from cmd ?

Comment: You need to change the values to your extension, but to run using the cmd you need to filter the command and run the last 3 lines.